# Java X Y coordinates

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have been working on a Monopoly project for a couple of days now in order to improve my coding in Java.

Most of the board was done using the paint method and I had a hard time calculating where to position each square.I know it's not probably a good ideea to create a board this way I have been told by a friend but this is my first  big project in Java and as a programmer and I wana see what comes out of been from my own ideeas.

My next order of busines would be to set the positions of each piece while the players travers it and I am in  need of x y coordinates again.I should also mention I am using the SWING library for the GUI.

What I want to know if there is a way to get the xy cordinates of the interface while moving

Comment: you can try to create a small programm that shows you the x and y coordinate on mouseover or mouse click and by simulating like it it will be helpful to get x and y of appropriate points..

Comment: What do you mean while moving? Mouse movements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with two different types of coordinates you might mean:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

/* 
 * Get X coordinate of panel's origin relative to the parent's 
 * upper left corner measured in pixels. 
 */
panel.getX();

/* 
 * Get coordinates of mouse click relative to the source component.
 */
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        Point p = event.getPoint();
    }
});
```